# Lockless increment if greater than

Tags: c++, atomic, compare-and-swap

Is anybody aware of a lockless way to perform what is logically equivalent to a compare_and_swap_if_greater_than()? We have compare_and_swap(), which is really compare_and_swap_if_equal(). The best I have right now is to use a spin mutex, but I think withclever uses of history variables, loops, and compare_and_swap() it may be possible to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static void CompareAndSwapIfGreaterThan(ref int location, int newValue) {
  while(true) {
    var currentValue=Thread.VolatileRead(ref location);
    if(newValue<=currentValue
      || Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location, newValue, currentValue)==currentValue) {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. I think minimally you need a loop around the latter condition in the OR for the case where != currentValue. I could certainly be wrong though.

Comment: @tgoodhart:  I think the outer loop takes care of that case.  This is a pretty standard formulation for updating a value atomically using compare&swap...  Read old value; compute new value; conditionally store new value; and try again if someone beat you to it.  I believe this works.